# Why does ImportString["1c", "Table"] eat the letter c?

Tags: import

I have some whitespace-separated matrix data that I read with `Import[..., "Table"]`.  The data contained mixed strings and numbers (the strings are for row and column names).

I noticed this weird behaviour:

```
ImportString["123c", "Table"]

(* ==> {{123}} *)
```

Mathematica ate the letter `c`!! Why?

It doesn't eat any other letters:

```
ImportString["123a", "Table"]
(* {{"123a"}} *)

ImportString["123e", "Table"]
(* {{"123e"}} *)
```

What is the explanation and what is a good workaround?

---

**Update:**

It seems that this happens even if the labels is quoted in the file:

```
ImportString["\"24c\"", "CSV"]

(* ==> {{24}} *)
```

Comment: It's either a bug or it's interpreting `123c` as some non-string datatype, I just can't figure out what.

Comment: This is because it is SMILES :). Try this `StringFormat["123c"]` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wg28d.png)

Comment: Also notice what it says in help if the format specification is not given: "attempts to determine the format of the string from its contents."  the keyword is `attempt`. I do not think this is a good way to make functions. This is all fuzzy type programming. What does "Attempt" actually mean? How do I grade this attempt? A grade? B grade? 85% attempt? A function should be clear. It should tell exactly what is the input and what is the output.

Comment: @Nasser The reason why I consider this very bad is that I didn't even notice the incorrect import until I started doing some consistency checks on the data.  Only after that did I discover that this lead to incorrect results (I had both labels "24" and "24c", and they needed to be distinguishable).  Most people wouldn't suspect that importing a simple CSV or similar file will change their data.  It's completely unexpected, and thus difficult to discover, and will easily lead to ruined work.  `"CurrencyTokens" -> None` should be the default.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Mathematica is interpreting `c` as a currency marker.  This is controlled by the `"CurrencyTokens"` import option for `"Table"`.

The default setting for `"CurrencyTokens"` is

```
{{"$ ", "£", "¥", "€"}, {"c ", "¢", "p ", "F "}}
```

so this also happens with the letters `p` or `F`.

The workaround is

```
ImportString["123c", "Table", "CurrencyTokens" -> None]
(* {{"123c"}} *)
```

Notice:  The same applies to the `"CSV"`, `"TSV"` and `"List"` import formats.