# Parsing a CSV file using Interpreter

Tags: import, code-review, csv-format, parsing, interpreter

The new [`Interpreter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpreter.html) functionality in version 10 looks like it has the potential to make parsing custom data formats very easy.  I'm trying to create a CSV parser.

---

**Requirements:**

1. Rows are delimited by newlines, columns are delimited by commas.
2. Entries can be numbers, strings (everything that's quoted or can't be interpreted as a number is a string).
3. Commas in quoted strings must be ignored.
4. Empty elements are allowed, e.g. this row contains three empty elements: `,,`.  They're delimited by two commas.  These can be parsed to either `Null` or `""`.

My actual problem doesn't have requirement 3.  I put in more requirements in the hopes to make the question more generally useful, and I meant to accept answers that satisfy only a subset of these. (Perhaps this was misguided.) In the meantime Carlo's answer explains that requirement 3. can't be met.

**Test data:**

```
,"one","2"
"a",1,2
"b",3,"4c"
"c",5,x
"d",6,"seven, eight"
```

Or ready to paste Mathematica string:

```
csv = ",\"one\",\"2\"\n\"a\",1,2\n\"b\",3,\"4c\"\n\"c\",5,x\n\"d\",6,\"seven,eight\""
```

**Parsed result should `MatchQ` this pattern:**

```
{{Null | "" | Missing[___], "one", "2"}, 
 {"a", 1, 2}, 
 {"b", 3, "4c"}, 
 {"c", 5, "x"}, 
 {"d", 6, "seven, eight"}}
```

How close can we get to this result, using `Interpreter`?

---

Here's a first try:

```
int = Interpreter[
  DelimitedSequence[
   DelimitedSequence[
    Restricted["String", "\"" ~~ ___ ~~ "\""] | "Number" | "String",
    ","
    ],
   "\n"
   ]
  ]

int[csv]
```

What it gets wrong:

- fails on point 4. (this is actually important for me)
- fails on point 3.
- doesn't unquote strings

It may not be possible to implement all the features I request using `Interpreter`, but how close can we get?  How much time and effort can `Interpreter` save when attacking this problem?  Preferably it should be possible to offload most of the processing to interpreter and reach the desired result by adding minimal pre and/or post-processing.

Comment: How close can we get to this result using `Interpreter` but not `Interpreter["CSV"]@str` :)

Comment: @Pickett Actually my motivation for this is that the built-in CSV import has too many problems and I'm required to create my own.  I'll tweak the test case to break the built-in CSV import even more.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about such problems. That makes the question even more valid, though I already gave it a +1.

Comment: I don't think this is a good use case for Interpreter. I don't dispute that we can do better, but I suggest you look at SemanticImport instead.

Comment: @Pickett Problems with `Import[..., "CSV"]`: Some problems: `4c` is interpreted as currency and converted to the number `4` instead of being read as `"4c"`.  I can fix this with `"CurrencyTokens" -> None`.  Then `"2"` is again read as the number `2`, not a string, which is again a problem.  I thought it would be better to explicitly restrict what data types to interpret and how.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon I wasn't sure if `Interpreter` was meant for this actually.   If that's the case then I better not push it with this application and remove this question.  However, if there's a good solution using `SemanticImport` and if `SemanticImport` doesn't require an internet connection (does it?) then it would be better to give an answer using a `SemanticImport` solution, mention that `Interpreter` is not for this, and keep the question.

Comment: You can unquote strings by doing something like this: `Interpreter[DelimitedSequence[StringReplace[#, "\"" ~~ a___ ~~ "\"" :> a] & | "Number" | "String", ","]]["\"a\",1,2,c"]`

Comment: @Carlo Why does this fail? --> `Interpreter[StringReplace[#, "\"" ~~ a___ ~~ "\"" :> a] & | "String"][""]`.  Is it a bug or am I misunderstanding how it should work?  `Interpreter["String"][""]` doesn't fail, nor does `Interpreter[StringReplace[#, "\"" ~~ a___ ~~ "\"" :> a] &][""]`.

Comment: Here's the idea: the first returns `Missing["NoInput"]` so we try the second that is `Missing["NoInput"]` as well. Since we considered the first equivalent to the Failure, we can't treat the second as good.

Comment: Can you explain how CSV is broken?  I'm only seeing 3 differences.  1: The \"2\" in the top-right corner is expected to be a string but is in fact a number.  I believe that's correct -- the expectation is wrong -- since quotes in CSV delimit the content, and are not part of the content.  2: The "4c" in the middle-right is becoming a numeric 4.  See ref/format/CSV and stop "c" from being interpreted as "cents" by setting "CurrencyTokens"->None. 3: "seven,eight" is not having a space inserted after the comma.  Why is that wrong?

Comment: @JeremyMichelson Can you come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica)?  There are too many comments already.

Comment: @Carlo Is Interpreter meant to be used as a general parser mechanism?  Unfortunately `Interpreter["Number"]` is just too slow to be able to use it to implement parsers for different file formats. [Please see here.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56926/12)  Is there a chance that performance will be improved for 10.0.1 or 10.0.2?

Comment: @Szabolcs No not really. It's been mainly been designed for use with FormFunction and APIFunction. Performance will definitely be improved, but I don't think the main design goal for Interpreter is general parsing, there is SemanticImport and other stuff yet to come that will cover that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I worked on Interpreter.

As far as the implentation is now, the DelimitedSequence parser does not support quoting, so what you want can't be done. We'll try to add it in a future version.

Comment: Hi Carlo, thanks for the response.  This was really a theoretical question, and I didn't mean to point out any faults with `Interpreter`, I'm just trying to learn how to make the best use of it.  You mean that requirement 3. can't be met with `Interpreter`, right?  In my *actual* application I don't need point 3., but I do need 4.  What I did was that I broke up the lines using `StringSplit[#, ",", All]&` (note `All`, which preserves empty entries), then applied `Interpreter` to each entry, and finally unquoted each quoted string.  Could I have done better with the new functionality?

Comment: (The reason why I put more requirements in the question than my actual application was to make the question broader and more generally useful.  I meant to accept answers that satisfy only a subset of the requirements.  I should spell this out.)

Comment: I think a nullable string pattern might also be useful (and can probably be written). However I think that DelimitedSequence here is at fault. For example `Interpreter["Boolean"][""]` returns `False`, but `Interpreter[DelimitedSequence["Boolean", ","]][",True"]` returns only `{True}` and this is probably a bug.

Comment: `StringSplit` also behaves like this without its third argument: `StringSplit[",1", ","]` ---> `{"1"}` and `StringSplit[",1", ",", All]` ---> `{"", "1"}`.  Maybe a similar syntax could be used?  The standard behaviour to ignore delimiters at the start/end makes sense if the delimiter is whitespace.

Answer (score 9):

This is an ideal use case for `SemanticImport`, but unfortunately it has issues getting the commas right in version 10.0.

Luckily, version 10.0.1 has already fixed this bug:

[image]

Comment: Nice tease with v10.0.1 :)

Comment: I was trying to use SemanticImport for this sort of data in 10.1.0, but it is literally unusably slow when specifying column types explicitly. This takes 27 seconds on my computer: `SemanticImportString[ExportString[RandomReal[10, {5000, 5}], "Table"], {Real, Real, Real,Real, Real}];`  Is there going to be a fix for this?

Comment: Because of problems like this one (and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55245/12)) I am actually getting quite a bit of real pressure to use R instead.  It's very hard to explain to the decision-makers why I would need to use a very expensive piece of software like Mathematica when R is free and can import data quickly and accurately, especially when I had to correct my results the next day as I discovered that Mathematica imported some data incorrectly.  I really hope WRI will give higher priority to practical user needs.

Comment: @Szabolcs `Real` isn't a valid type for `SemanticImport`. It only happens to work because `Interpreter[Real]` means the same as `Interpreter["Real"]`, so `SI` is delegating to `Interpreter`, which is much, much slower. If you pass `"Real"` to `SemanticImport`, it works fast. I get 1.4 seconds for your example.

Comment: @Taliesin Thank you!!! This is great!