# What's real analogue for FromDigits?

Tags: functions, conversion

FromDigits only works for integer strings.  What's its real-number analogue?

Comment: RealDigits? as in `RealDigits[ToExpression["1234.234532"]]` gives `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 4}`

Comment: What's the format of the input? If its a simple string, `ToExpression` or some `Interpreter`, or ``Internal`StringToDouble``

Comment: Internal`StringToDouble is fine. ToExpression is too dangerous in general Interpreter is not backwards compatible.

Comment: As an example, `ImportString["1.234 5.678e2", "Table"]` might do the sort of thing that you want.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good question, but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a perfect solution.

1. You can use [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToExpression.html), e.g. `ToExpression["1.23"]`.  **But:** (1) this gives no error checking (2) it's a serious security risk if you obtain the string from users (and it can go things go haywire in general if the string comes from an unknown source)
2. `` Internal`StringToDouble `` can parse floating point numbers in C format.  It accepts both `"1.24"` and `"12.4e-1"`.  **But:** (1) is is undocumented so there are no guarantees of compatibility or that it won't crash your kernel (2) it still doesn't offer error checking
3. In version 10, there's `Interpreter`.  For example, `Interpreter["Number"]["1.24"]`.  It is flexible, supports both `1.23e4` and `1.23*10^4`.  It provides error checking.  It's probably the best choice.  **But:**  It is very slow, and unsuitable for parsing a long list of numbers.  Parsing only 1000 numbers takes a full second on my i7 machine.  It doesn't make it possible to implement e.g. [a CSV parser in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56876/12).

So none of these is a perfect solution.  There's always the choice to implement your own in C if you need all of speed, reliability and error checking.  But it takes a lot of work to do this.

---

Thanks to @chuy in the chatroom, here's a way to make `ToExpression` safer:

```
toNum[e_String] := Replace[
  Quiet@ToExpression[e, InputForm, HoldComplete],
  {HoldComplete[n : (_Integer | _Real)] :> n, _ -> $Failed}
]
```

This is safer than using `ToExpression` alone and much faster than `Interpreter["Number"]`.  It handles numbers that follow the Mathematica syntax, so keep in mind that strange looking things such as `toNum["16^^abc"]` will work.

Comment: I concur on the slowness of Interpreter. It was probably developed to parse WolframAlpha input, i.e., just a single line. It's totally and utterly useless for any serious big data project.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s first code line of Stephen Wolfram’s [Pi or Pie?! Celebrating Pi Day of the Century](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2015/03/pi-or-pie-celebrating-pi-day-of-the-centuryand-how-to-get-your-very-own-piece-of-pi/) blog post:

```
PiString = StringDrop[ToString[N[Pi, 10^2]], {2}];
```

Stephen converted the first 10 million digits of π to a string without a decimal point, but I’ve taken just the first 100 digits. The real number analogue of FromDigits would be:

```
PiApproximate = FromDigits[PiString]/10^(10^2 - 1);
```

Convert this approximate π into a string:

```
PiStringApproximate = StringDrop[ToString[N[PiApproximate, 10^2]], {2}];
```

and yes, it exactly matches the real thing:

```
PiStringApproximate === PiString
```

Comment: I believe the question is: How can we parse floating point numbers?  This doesn't answer that.

Comment: @Szabolcs Where do I find this chat that you mention in your answer?

Comment: Click the StackExchange logo at the top of the page, and click chat.  Or click here: [chat].  Unlike the main site, the chat is free, any topic goes.

Comment: For the interested reader's benefit, here's the @chuy chat [link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20848966#20848966).