# Interpreter fails to obey significant figure specifications

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, numerical-value

Consider the following example, where we [specify the precision of the numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) to perform a significant figures calculation:

```
(341.7`4 - 22.0`3) + (0.002240`4 * 814005`6)

(* 2143. *)
```

It may be the case that we receive this input as a string, and evaluate it to yield the proper result:

```
str = "(341.7`4 - 22.0`3) + (0.002240`4 * 814005`6)"
ToExpression[str]
(* 2143. *)
```

[Evaluating arbitrary strings is unsafe, so using an Interpreter to limit ourselves to numerical calculations is better.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/296153/63709)  **However, the numeric [Interpreter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpreter.html) types do not appear to obey the significant figure calculation:**

```
Interpreter["ComputedNumber"]@str
(* 2143.1 *) 

Interpreter["MathExpression"]@str
(* 2143.07 *)
```

(Of course, we could use the `Expression` Interpreter, but that gets us back to the unsafe behaviour):

```
Interpreter["Expression"]@str
(* 2143. *)
```

**Thoughts?** (I'm hesitating to say the b-u-g word, but...) (running this on 14.0)

Comment: It looks like it does obey the precision when you give it only a number (which is done locally without connecting to their server), eg. ```Interpreter["ComputedNumber"]["5`2"] // FullForm```. However, when it actually needs to perform some calculation (by connecting to the Wolfram Knowledgebase), the final result will be given with the machine precision. This could be mentioned in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/interpreter/ComputedNumber.html), although it's probably not a very common use case ...

Comment: If you know what restrictions you need, one could use: `Interpreter[Restricted["Expression", {Plus, Minus, Times}]][str]`

Comment: @Chuy That's really slick and [not so well documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Restricted.html)

Comment: I agree it could be better documented.  You can see better examples in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/interpreter/Expression.html.