# Importing a string such as "3d456" from a CSV file causes trouble

Tags: import, data, csv-format

I have a CSV file I'm importing with `Import` and it consistently crashes Mathematica. It turns out the culprit is one particular value of an ID field that was something like "3d456" but with a bunch more numbers after the 456.

The problem becomes clear if you try to import that as CSV directly:

```
ImportString["3d456", "CSV"]
```

The output is a 3 followed by 456 zeros. In other words, it's treating that string as a number in scientific notation. (Same thing if the "d" is an "e", which would be the more common representation.)

This threw me for quite a loop. And Mathematica is doing this despite that ID being in double quotes in the actual CSV file, which seems wrong.

So I think the most general version of my question is: How do I ensure that fields in a CSV file that are in quotes get imported as strings?

Or other workarounds for not letting something like "3d456" parse as a 457-digit integer.

Comment: This issue is also described in the documentation of [`"CSV"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html) in "Possible issues", 3rd example - as suggested there, you could set `"Numeric"->False` if you don't have any numeric inputs

Comment: The `d`-notation is used by Fortran if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: ReadList can help if your data file is properly structured (rectangular table with consistent row structure l

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a little preprocessing followed by a little post-processing?

First, let's contrive some random but reproducible data with of the kind you working with.

```
SeedRandom[1];
  With[{m = 3, n = 5},
  data = RandomInteger[100, {m, n}];
  Module[{i, j},
    {i, j} = RandomChoice /@ {Range[m], Range[n]};
    data[[i, j]] = "3d456"; 
    data]]
```

> `{{80, 14, 0, 67, 3}, {65, 100, 23, 97, 68}, {74, 15, "3d4", 4, 100}}`

Now let's pretend that we have read in a CSV file with the above data as a single string.

```
csvData = ExportString[data, "CSV"]
```

> `"80,14,0,67,3\n65,100,23,97,68\n74,15,'3d456',4,100\n"`

which looks like

[image: data]

in a notebook. The preprocessing changes the internal double-quotes into single-quotes.

```
preData = StringReplace[csvData, {",\"" -> ",'", "\"," -> "',"}]
```

> `"80,14,0,67,3\n65,100,23,97,68\n74,15,'3d456',4,100\n"`

Now we do the conversion to Mathematica data.

```
mmaData = ImportString[preData, "CSV"]
```

> `{{80, 14, 0, 67, 3}, {65, 100, 23, 97, 68}, {74, 15, "'3d456'", 4, 100}}`

It's not quite right because of the single-quotes. The post-processing  gets rid of them.

```
postData = Map[Switch[#, _String, StringTrim[#, "'"], _, #] &, mmaData, {2}]
```

> `{{80, 14, 0, 67, 3}, {65, 100, 23, 97, 68}, {74, 15, "3d456", 4, 100}}`

```
postData == data
```

> `True`

#### Update

The OP asked for a function that would implement the procedure described above. I am posting such a function, but without any discussion of file system functions used or why I made the choices that I made. This update would be better if such a discussion were included, but I simply do not have the time to write it.

```
csv::fail = "import from `1` failed";
csv::ok = "data imported from `1`";
getCSVData[] :=
  Module[{filePath, str, csvData},
    filePath =
      SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", {"*.csv", {"CSV Files" -> {"*.csv", ".CSV"}}}];
    If[filePath === $Canceled, Return[{}]];
    str = ReadString[filePath];
    If[str === $Failed, Message[csv::fail, filePath]; Return[{}]];
    csvData =
      ImportString[StringReplace[str, {",\"" -> ",'", "\"," -> "',"}], "CSV"];
    Map[Switch[#, _String, StringTrim[#, "'"], _, #] &, csvData, {2}]]
```

Comment: Really nice solution! Thank you! If you wrap it up in a self-contained function I'll make it the accepted answer. (Ok, I think I'll make it the accepted answer regardless.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Import[..., {"CSV", "RawData"}]` to treat all fields as strings. Unfortunately that means all fields whether or not they're in quotes. So then you need to use `ToExpression` to parse specific fields into numbers.

Comment: And `ToExpression` won't actually parse notations like `123e4`. [Nor is it secure.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172553/12)  And there's no alternative.  The situation is completely unsatisfactory.  `Import` is just not very well designed and can cause a lot of damage if you're unlucky: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55245/12