# Importing a CSV file hangs up

Tags: import, csv-format

Ver.12.1.0.0 hangs up when I do "Import" a csv file
that contain an entry ""000000000000000000000000000000000000000053253943D755066515000057",
while this csv file can be read by EXCEL and Mathematical allows Import
of the resulting xlsx file.
What can I do, other than reporting this to the Mathematica support?

Comment: The question looks unclear. Can you add a code sample that reproduce the issue? Anyway, I guess I might have understood your question. Do you mean the following code sample hangs?: `Export["test.csv", "000000000000000000000000000000000000000053253943D755066515000057"]; 
Import["test.csv"]`

Comment: You could also change the `D` to a an `X`. OI think Import tries to be smart and thinks that `D` as a Fortran version of `E` ... , i.e., 
`ImportString["1D7", "CSV"]` gives `10^7`.
I wished Import would be better documented and less "smart".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing a string such as "3d456" from a CSV file causes trouble](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173007/importing-a-string-such-as-3d456-from-a-csv-file-causes-trouble)

Answer (score 2):

This imports all entries as a string

```
Import["test.csv", {"CSV", "RawData"}]
```